# Rust-analyzer throws "unresolved-macro" despite disabling "macro-error" and "unresolved-macro-call"

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I'm writing some backend code in rust using VSCode and of course the rust-analyzer.
As many others, I have gotten issues with linting of macros by rust-anylyzer.
I tried suppressing the linting/errors in `settings.json`, but with very little success.

```
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "matklad.rust-analyzer",
    "rust-analyzer.diagnostics.disabled": [
        "macro-error",
        "unresolved-macro-call",
        "unresolved-import"
    ],
    "rust-analyzer.experimental.procAttrMacros": false,
    "rust-analyzer.procMacro.enable": false
```

Yet somehow I *still* receive linting and error displays of unresolved-macro-errors.

I have also tried setting `procAttrMacros` and `procMacro.enable` to true, error still occurs. All github/so-questions related to the matter just suggest fiddling with `rust-analyzer.diagnostics.disabled property`, which I have, but that has not fixed the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just double checking, does `cargo check` return these errors? or is it just rust-analyzer?

Comment: Just ran it, it is *only* rust-analyzer that returns these errors. Cargo check returns no issues. The project also compiles without issue with cargo run

Comment: Ur settings are working for me. After restart of VSCode my warnings vanished

Comment: man thanks, your setting makes the error gone!!!